# Matching up incoming packets with their corresponding request (with noise)

Tags: networking, filter, response, rpc, fuzzing

I'm currently building a black-box fuzzing tool and I have encountered the following problem:

Suppose I send a server a fuzzed packet that I construct and get some packets back from the server. I also get some additional packets from other parts of the same server.

Provided I can look at all the incoming and outgoing packets (this is not a request-response system, it's an RPC-based online game) and I have no information what the response should look like, how do I filter out those packets that were sent in response to the fuzzed packet from the rest of the stream?

Just an example: you send an RPC like "give a player a gun with ID 5" and the server sends that player RPCs like "give me an array of the guns you have" and "tell me how much ammo you got". I want to see how the server reacts if I send malformed input, e.g. negative or big integers, in this case. My problem is the fact that the server sends these on a random basis all the time, so I want to filter out the requests that are sent in response to my fuzzed RPC.

A statistical approach will do as I assume there's no way to determine this with full confidence.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that "it's not a request-response system, it's RPC-based" should not change a thing to the classic scheme - unless you/I missed some details from your question:

- You must construct a tuple structure from the request with (source IP, destination IP, source port, destination port),
- and then watch for reverse tuple (destination IP, source IP,
  destination port, source port) packets to catch the response(s).

EDIT: for TCP of course - for connectionless protocols, well, that's a game of heuristic guesses.

Comment: I know it's not relevant, I just wanted to make sure it's clear that there's no "request ID" or anything like that in the protocol. I updated my post with some more information.

Comment: @user49277 Yes, sure. My response stand.